# SQLCODE=-5005 while connecting to db2 database from PHP

Tags: php, db2, db2-luw

I am testing PHP + Db2 connectivity. I am following this URL - https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2/blob/master/README.md

I have this sample code:

```
<?php
$database = 'casedb';
$user = 'db2test';
$password = 'XXXXXXX';
$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);
echo "IN";
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed: " . db2_conn_errormsg();
}
echo "OUT";
?>
```

If I run it as standalone PHP program, the connection succeeds.

```
# php connect.php
INConnection succeeded.OUT
```

If I open this PHP page via web browser, it shows me this error:
http://9.30.XX.XX/connect.php

```
INConnection failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3". SQLCODE=-5005OUT
```

Not sure where this SQL5005 error is coming from.

```
SQL5005C  The operation failed because the database manager failed to
      access either the database manager configuration file or the
      database configuration file.
Explanation: 
The DB2 database product uses two types of configuration files:
Database manager configuration file
         Created when a DB2 database manager instance is created, the
     database manager configuration file contains parameters that
     affect system resources at the instance level. There is also
     one database manager configuration file for each client
     installation, which contains information about the client
     enabler for a specific workstation. The database manager
     configuration file is named db2systm and is located in the
     instance directory.
Database configuration file
         Created when a database is created, the database configuration
     file contains parameters that affect the use of that database.
     The database configuration file for each database is named
     SQLDBCONF, and stored along with other control files for that
     database in the directory named "SQLnnnnn" (where nnnnn is a
     number assigned when the database was created.)
```

I have db2cli.ini configured for target database. Still no success.

Any hints please? Thank you.

Comment: Is the PHP running on Linux or Windows? Is the PHP running on the same hostname as the site you browse to when it fails?  If you are browsing to localhost, where PHP is installed, which *user account* runs the web server process? If you become that user (su, sudo, runas...), can that user run php standalone to connect successfully?

Comment: PHP is running on Linux. My browser is running on remote host (which is mac).

But you gave an excellent hint of running PHP code as non-root user.
```
[db2test@linnets1 html]$ php connect.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so' - libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db2_connect() in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 5
```

I'm debugging further.

Comment: I can run the program as non-root user successfully now. But still cant call it via web browser. Not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be nice to review below Q&A:

[How to use PHP Locale functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773588/how-to-use-php-locale-functions)

It tells that we need: 
**setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale) and localeconv()**

And try to set one of: "usa", "america", "united states", "united-states", or "us"
See below for other countries/values:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Hope this helps.